# Jquery Galleria: autoplay again after interaction

Tags: jquery, slideshow, galleria, autoplay

I'm using Jquery Galleria for my website.

What I want is: autoplay slideshow on load, stop it when I click on thumbnails or navigation, but after idle time the autoplay continue.

With pauseOnInteraction:true , the autoplay will not continue after click.
With pauseOnInteraction:false, the autoplay will not stop at all.

How can I do this?

Thanks, Eric

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the [idle_enter](http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/api/events/#idle-enter) event like this:

```
this.bind('idle_enter', function(e) { 
    this.play();
});
```

**Implementation**

If you are using 1.2.4 (released yesterday), you can implement this using `Galleria.ready`:

```
Galleria.ready(function() {
    this.bind('idle_enter', function(e) { 
        this.play();
    });
});
```

Or use the `extend` option:

```
$('#galleria').galleria({
    extend: function() {
        this.bind('idle_enter', function(e) { 
            this.play();
        });
    }
});
```

You can set the time Galleria will wait before entering idle mode using the `idleTime` option.